# .Net Framework Multi-Tenant OIDC Authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, openid-connect

We have 3 applications (Desktop, Mobile, Excel Addon), which means 3 client IDs, that need to call our APIs.

Is it possible to configure our API to work with those 3 client IDs?
Here's the current config :

```
            string OidcAuthority = Config.OidcAuthority;
            string OidcRedirectUrl = Config.OidcRedirectUrl;
            string OidcClientId = Config.OidcClientId;
            string OidcClientSecret = Config.OidcClientSecret;

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = OidcAuthority,
                ClientId = OidcClientId,
                ClientSecret = OidcClientSecret,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = OidcRedirectUrl,
                RedirectUri = OidcRedirectUrl,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId                    
            };
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
```

Edit:

Here's the code we had when we were using oauth2 and Auth0 services.

```
            var domain = Config.Domain;
            var apiIdentifier = Config.ApiIdentifier;
            var keyResolver = new OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver(domain);

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = apiIdentifier,
                        ValidIssuer = domain,
                        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, parameters) => keyResolver.GetSigningKey(kid)
                    }
                });
```

I know I have to use something similar but I have 3 possible apps that could generate a token, which means 3 possible audiences...
How should I do it?

Edit2:

Here's the code to get issue an access token in the desktop app (Ext JS):

```
    userLogin: function(){
        let deferred = new Ext.Deferred();
        let self = this;

        if (window.location.href.indexOf("#id_token") >= 0) {
            return self.processLoginResponse(deferred, self);
        }
        
        var settings = {
            authority: 'https://' + ONELOGIN_SUBDOMAIN + '.onelogin.com/oidc/2',    
            client_id: ONELOGIN_CLIENT_ID,
            redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
            response_type: 'id_token token',
            scope: 'openid profile',
        
            filterProtocolClaims: true,
            loadUserInfo: true
        };
        var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(settings);

        mgr.signinRedirect({state:'some data'}).then(function() {
            deferred.resolve("signin redirect");
        }).catch(function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    processLoginResponse: function(deferred, self){            
        var settings = {
            authority: 'https://' + ONELOGIN_SUBDOMAIN + '.onelogin.com/oidc/2',    
            client_id: ONELOGIN_CLIENT_ID,
            redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
            response_type: 'id_token token',
            scope: 'openid profile',
        
            filterProtocolClaims: true,
            loadUserInfo: true
        };

        var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(settings);
        mgr.signinRedirectCallback().then(function(user) {
            Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.id_token });
            deferred.resolve("user signed in");
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Why to have 3 apps (clientIDs), instead you can have just one app, but 3 all possible redirect URLs. I think, only thing that is different among 3 apps is the redirect URL.

Comment: It could work for only the mobile and desktop app, the excel add-on requires a password grant flow or something similar.
Another variable is that we need MFA for mobile/desktop but not for the excel addon as it's not compatible with the service we are using (OneLogin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WEBSITE v API TECH STACKS**

The tech stack you are using is designed for websites. When an HTML page is loaded, if there is no valid authentication cookie, the user is abruptly redirected to login.

Native clients instead call APIs via direct HTTP requests, and the above stack would attempt to redirect these requests, which would be the wrong behaviour.

Instead native apps should each implement their own OIDC flow to get an access token, using their own Client ID. The [RFC8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) standard describes these  flows. APIs should not need to know Client IDs of their callers.

**API TECH STACK BEHAVIOUR**

It is possible and usually recommended to use the same APIs for multiple related clients. If using C#, it is common for APIs to use the following option, where APIs validate JWT access tokens on every request:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Config.Authority;
        options.Audience = Config.Audience;
    });
```

This is the Microsoft package you include in order to use it:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.10" />
```

Typically the authority is the base URL of your authorization server and the audience is a value you define to represent one or more related APIs:

```
authority: https://login.example.com
audience: api.example.com
```

If required, APIs with the same audience can then forward the JWT to each other, so that they can all authorize requests in the same way. The Microsoft security stack will download and cache the token signing public key from the Authorization Server, then use it to digitally verify received access tokens and build a ClaimsPrincipal.

Once the JWT is validated you can also trust the claims it issued and authorize based on them, eg by defining authorization policies like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("myPolicy", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            context.User.HasClaim(claim => 
                claim.Type == "myClaim" && claim.Value == "myValue
            )
        )
    );
});
```

One way to code authorization at the logic level is for your controllers to then apply an Authorize attribute in order to apply the policy:

```cs
[HttpGet("/api/resource")]
[Authorize(Policy = "myPolicy")]
public IActionResult GetResource()
{
    return Ok(new { data = "My data" });
}
```

**JWT VALIDATION IN .NET FRAMEWORK**

In the older .NET framework, the concepts are identical, with the only difference being that authorization attributes may work a little differently. Here is how a JWT is validated, where the Issuer / Authority still represents the base URL of the authorization server:

```cs
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidIssuer = Config.Issuer;
            ValidAudience = Config.Audience;
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks.
Do you have any examples of the options to provide for this method ? The one I have contains an API identifier which won't work in my case as I have 3 APIs.

Comment: Well I made some updates to describe how an  OAuth secured API would behave for native clients. The other part of the solution would be to implement OIDC flows for native apps, which is a bigger topic.

Comment: We are using .Net Framework not .Net Core sadly

Comment: It is no different - I have seen these tech stacks change, but the important thing to understand is the design pattern. I added the .NET framework equivalent above.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It looks a lot like what we did with Auth0.
Does it mean I have to add the audience to the sign-in request for the client?
If yes, do you know how to do it using OIDC? I Edited the question with a sample of the sign-in request.

Comment: The audience for access tokens is configured against each client in the authorization server. It is an array and represents the APIs that the client can call. If they are a set of related apps, consider using the same value for all of them. Nothing needs to change in the sign in request for clients.

Comment: I'll dig in the platform (OneLogin) to see if I can find where to add the audience, thanks.

Comment: It seems the audience is already configured, the APIs work without having to do anything in the authorization server.
Last question, using 'UseJwtBearerAuthentication' I don't need to do anything regarding token validity/expiration?

Comment: That will work by default - just give it a test. wnd ensure that API tesponses are useful to clients - you should see a 401 status for missing, invalid or expired tokens.

Comment: All good, thanks Gary